# Test Methods are not included while running Maven Test

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium

I am running maven Test from eclipse but maven test is not including the test classes, as i have already specify the annotation and other Pom.xml configuration.

My Java Code:

```
package com.testingMeven;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class HelloWorld {

    @Test
    public void login()
    {
        System.out.println("First Maven Test");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

    }
}
```

My POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.testingMeven</groupId>
  <artifactId>testing</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>testing</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.42.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.3.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Using IDE Eclipse JUNO,

And got the execution output in console as below, It is not considering the Test Class for Execution.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building testing 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ testing ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\s\workspace\testing\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ testing ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ testing ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\s\workspace\testing\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ testing ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ testing ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\s\workspace\testing\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.831s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Feb 14 18:15:08 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/171M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not sure what misconfiguration I did.

Help is really Appreciated.

Comment: Is your testclass located under `src/test/java`?

Comment: yes its under src/test/java?

Comment: I have call it through Eclipse ->Project -> Run As -> Maven Test

Comment: Name your test class `HelloWorldTest` instead of `HelloWorld`

Comment: @Tunaki , Wow Its Working. Thank you Very Much. But I haven't Understood the logic behind it... :)

Comment: Using maven-plugins as dependencies is simply wrong.